# Javascript with X decimal places without removing zeros

Tags: javascript

I want to print a decimal number with exactly four decimal places with the following constraints.

- The result must be a number
- All decimal places must shown,
  even they are zero

I've tried to use this.

```
function addDecimalPlaces(number, p){
    return parseFloat(number.toFixed(p));
}

addDecimalPlaces(.2000000, 4); // return 0.2 but I want 0.2000
addDecimalPlaces(1.238894, 4); // return 1.2389 
addDecimalPlaces(6.30000, 4);  // return 6.3 but I want 6.3000
```

After using `parseFloat()` removes the decimal places if they are zero.

Any idea?

Comment: If you want to control how your numbers are displayed, you need to format them as as string. `6.3` and `6.30000` are the same number as far as JavaScript is concerned. Your two constraints cannot be met.

Comment: I'm assuming you need it to be padded with 0 for visual purpose only, in that case string is sufficient. You will have to covert back to float whenever you need to use the value. You can still use string value while the input type says `number`.